# Homework problem, available fields for queen in chess

Tags: c

I have school asignment due tommorow and would apreaciate some help.  My assigment is "Create a program that determines which chess board fields are available to the queen from the field where it is located. The chessboard is presented as a matrix 8x8. Queen's position is entered from the keyboard into [letter] [number]. And the result is saved in a string. "

Iam kinda stuck on how to continiue, i think i need like 8 different if's. 2 for horizontal, 2 for vertical and 4 for diagonals, but i dont know how to do them.

```
int main()
{

    int horizontal,vertical,i,j,current;
    char poz;

    printf("Enter the horizontal position of queen(A-H)\n");
    scanf("%s", &poz);

    if(poz=='A')
    {
        horizontal=1;
    }
    else if (poz=='B')
    {
        horizontal=2;
    }   
    else if (poz=='C')
    {
        horizontal=3;
    }
    else if (poz=='D')
    {
        horizontal=4;
    }   
    else if (poz=='E')
    {
        horizontal=5;
    }
    else if (poz=='F')
    {
        horizontal=6;
    }
    else if (poz=='G')
    {
        horizontal=7;
    }
    else if (poz=='H')
    {
        horizontal=8;
    }

    printf("Enter the vertical position of queen(1-8)\n");
    scanf("%d",&vertical);

    int n=8,m=8;

    int chess[8][8]={
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    };

    printf("Queen pos is %c-%d",poz,vertical );


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: It's time to learn about the [`switch` statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) and/or lookup tables and/or  the idea of character math (e.g. `horizontal = pos - 'A' + 1`). **Remember arrays in C are zero indexed**.

Comment: Even EBCDIC, a character set notorious for not having the alphabet it 26 consecutive codes, does have A-H consecutive, so indexing by (poz - 'A') will work fine. And you don't actually need the chess array for anything, since you're not actually placing in pieces on a board--you're just calculating which squares satisfy certain conditions.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &poz);` is going to segfault or cause weird errors because `poz` is only of type `char`. You should compile with warnings turned on.

Comment: Are there any other pieces on the board to block the queen?  Also, you do not mention what exactly your function is supposed to return.  8 8-charcters strings output to console?  An 8x8 array internally?  Also, you would be well to convert the position to 0-7, not 1-8 as in C, arrays are indexed base 0.  Lots of issues here for an assignment due tomorrow.  Procrastination gets you 'F' grades often...

Comment: There is nothing else on the board. My main function is supposed to return every field the queen can go to from her position, i dont have other function i think .

Comment: you might want to read: [queensProblem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle)  for some hints.

Comment: So tempted to post a recursive solution to this and have him try to explain that to prof.

Answer (score 0):

Strongly suggest the indexing be modified to 0...7 for both horizontal and vertical positions  Then include: (where 'r' is the row and 'c' is the column)

```
All positions in the column (0..7)/(c) where the queen is placed except (r)/(c) 

All positions in the row (r)/(0..7) where the queen is placed except (r)/(c)
```

Then starting at the queen placement (r)/(c)

```
all successive positions (r+1)/(c-1) until edge of board
all successive positions (r+1)/(c+1) until edge of board
all successive positions (r-1)/(c-1) until edge of board
all successive positions (r-1)/(c+1) until edge of board
```

The above is a few 'for()' statements and should be 'relatively' easy to implement.

Comment: Pretty sure they want "Algebreic Notation" as entry - hence the letter/number combo.  Also, ranges as 0 base would be 0 to 7 yes?